# Save as.. pop-up in angular.js

Tags: javascript, excel, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js. I have created a link called as "sample-list" and My requirement is after clicking on that link browse open a excel from the given location.
Please let me know the solution of it.

I have tried something like this in html. But getting error as "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/temp/project/abc.xls" 
sample list

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know you can't access the filesystem from Javascript

Comment: If you want to offer a file for download without a server where the file can be generated, then you will need to use Flash, or a similar plugin

Answer (score 0):

First of all it doesn't seem as though you're accessing your page through a web server (http). So when you use a relative file url like `relative_path/abc.xls`, it's trying to access a file relative to your file system which is not allowed by javascript for security reasons.

If you know where the file is going to be on your server, you can just use `window.open('absolute_or_relative_url.xls', '_blank');` or something more advanced like: 
[Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)